# How do I get a site unblocked from corporate firewalls

Tags: firewall, blacklist-prevention, palo-alto-networks

I have a pretty new site, nothing shady has ever happened with it, some of my friends have reported that they can't access said site at their company. How can I figure what lists I'm on and how to get off those lists? One of them indicated their firewall is Palo Alto Networks.

Comment: AFAIK there isn't really anything you can do to find what content filters you are blocked by.  The databases are kept pretty secret.  Your friends should report their problem to their IT department who will likely have a support contract with Palo Alto and will be able to submit the URL to them if it has been miss-classified in some way by their content filter.  This all assumes your site is being classified incorrectly.

Comment: Many corporations block sites by default until they are categorized or submitted as a requirement. There are many public and paid 'blacklists' for email servers and addresses, I assume there are probably similar lists for websites. I would do a google search for 'website blacklist' and see if you're on any of them.

Comment: So our site isn't really listed on any blacklists I've found online. The only notes are around email sending. We don't really send email so we haven't setup reverse references etc etc. It sounds like we just haven't been whitelisted. I guess another question is how is every blog under the sun visible on corporate wifi then?

Comment: Are you using shared hosting? If your site's IP address is shared with 200 other sites, then if just one of them is shady then all could be blocked. Solution would be to ask the provider to move you to another server.

Answer (score -1):

There are a whole host of companies that make firewalls and maintain their own lists of sites some categorizations some with risk ratings. These companies *do* allow you to submit a categorization for a site or request a review/change. The thing you should google for here is "URL Filtering" and "Firewall Companies".

By doing this I found that Palo Alto Networks classified our site as "porn". Why? I don't know. I found out by visiting: https://urlfiltering.paloaltonetworks.com (which is currently quite a broken page, but I got it to work with a little finagling)

Here are a list of companies and the urls to submit change requests:

- Palo Alto Networks: https://urlfiltering.paloaltonetworks.com
- Juniper Networks: http://mtas.surfcontrol.com/mtas/JuniperTest-a-Site.asp
- BrightCloud: https://www.brightcloud.com/tools/url-ip-lookup.php
- Barracuda: http://www.barracudacentral.org/report/website-category
- Sonic Wall: http://cfssupport.sonicwall.com/Support/web/eng/newui/viewRating.jsp
- Symantec Blue Coat: https://sitereview.bluecoat.com